# How to read plist from Apps's plist

Tags: iphone, sdk

Can anybody suggest me how to read plist file from app's plist file.

Thanks

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Comment: Why dont you try to find on google first ?? It saved your and our time. Well i have given answer check it.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it by `arrayWithContentsOfFile:` method. You need a `filePath` of your `.plist` file. See below example:-

```
NSString* plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"PlistFileName" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```